# How to let javascript get cookies in QWebView?

Tags: javascript, qt, cookies, qwebview

I use QWebView to load a html page which use javascript to get the cookies to do something.
But It seems javascript can’t set the cookies in QWebView.
What can I do to let it have that function?

Comment: I use the example(qt-4.8.x/demos/browser; qt-5.x/qtwebkit-examples/examples/webkitwidgets/browser) to visit that website, the javascript can’t get the cookies too.

Comment: I found if set the expires is 10000 years, it will can't set, 9999 years is ok, expires must be some special years.